# How to get a list of installed apps in Android 11

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-11, android-update-app

**This line is described on the developer site but I did not understand it perfectly**

```
Call getInstalledApplications() or getInstalledPackages(). Both methods should return a filtered list.
```

Actually, I need to test `Testing package visibility behavior`

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/testing

Answer (score 26):

There are 3 different ways of querying installed apps of the user in Android 11.

1. If you already know which apps you want to query just mention the
   package names inside the `<queries>` element in the
   `AndroidManifest`.

```
<manifest package="com.nikit.app">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.fake.app" />
        <package android:name="com.fake.game" />
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

2. In case you don’t know all the package names of the apps that you
   want to query but there is a set of apps with similar functionality
   that you want to query then you can use an intent filter inside the
   `<queries>` element according to your requirements like it has been
   done in the code snippet below.

```
<manifest package="com.nikit.app">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

The `<intent>` element looks like `<intent-filter>` but there are few differences.  element has the following restrictions:

- The `<intent>` element can have only one `<action>` element.
- The  element can only have the following attributes : `mimeType`,
  `scheme` and `host`.

3. If you want to query all the apps of the user like you were doing
   earlier, you need to include `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission in the
   `AndroidManifest`. It is a `normal` permission and it is granted as soon
   as the app is installed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU @shirley! but I have a doubt according to the developer site QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES is not recommended [link](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#all-apps), is there any side affect ?

Comment: hi@ajay bisaveni,About this maybe you can refer this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl)

Comment: @shirley In the 1st approach you mentioned, what if I want to add like 20+ package names? Is there any better way to do it? like wild card or something like `com.example.*`